# SmoothProgressBar in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android

How can I use a customized SmoothProgressBar(https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar) as a background for the SwiperefreshLayout(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is almost not possible without editing SwipeRefreshLayout source code but you could use SwipeRefreshLayout methods **setColorSchemeColors**, **setColorSchemeResources** for setting custom progress bar colors.